# Get Value from Object Swift

Tags: swift

How do I get a value of `RestaurantName` from the PFObject array?

I'm trying to get `objectId` in `RestaurantName` as a String.

#### Current Attempt

```
var stringObjectIds: [String] = self.restaurantObjects.map { $0.objectForKey("RestaurantName", "objectId") as String }
```

#### PFObject Array

```
[<FoodPhotoTest2: 0x7fa37e7ddb50, objectId: Jkl28Tcjjv, localId: (null)> {
    PhotoName = "Korean Dish";
    PhotoUploaded = "<PFFile: 0x7fa37e7f31d0>";
    RestaurantName = "<restauranttest2: 0x7fa37e784670, objectId: JNT2dLEL79>";
    UserUploaded = "<PFUser: 0x7fa37e4be170, objectId: wNJPsJDV6t>";
    Votes = 0;
}]
```

Comment: Does your current attempt give you an error? Unexpected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `restaurantObjects` contains `PFObject`s, then use `$0.objectId` in the map function.